# What is the best way to use mikro-orm with a rich-domain model?

Tags: mikro-orm

Sequelize lacks about Maping from DAO into Domain Models. I want to achieve a decoupled domain from the DAL, including from any ORM library so I think that the best way for this is to go to Repository Pattern with domain<->orm or something like that.

How is mikro-orm designed to achive the recommended idea from decoupling Domain and DAL and being the most productive + typescript capabilities as posible?

Comment: Hi there, author of MikroORM here. Do you have some examples of what would you like to achieve? MikroORM works pretty similar to jpa/hibernate/doctrine, so approaches from those ORMs should fit here as well. Is this about working with entities, or about their definition?

Comment: Hello @MartinAdámek I talking about Mapping Data into Domain Models. For instance, you have two tables in Postgresql but in your Rich Domain they are an Entity with an object value. How do you reconstitute them?

Comment: Well in case of 2 db tables, you should model it as two connected entities. Docs are full of examples about it, but I doubt you want something that is present in the docs, right? :] Mapping multiple tables into single entity is currently not supported.

Comment: I am always open for feature requests, but so far I failed to understand what exactly you want. Again, an example (more detailed example, maybe article, not one sentence) would help a lot.

Comment: Thanks a lot @MartinAdámek for your time and help. My thought is about maybe DB design requeriments can be improved in other way as domain it is. For instance, in my domain I have Account: Entity and AccountProfile: ValueObject. Account has an AccountProfile. AP cannot live without Account. But DB designer says that they must be in two diff tables. I dont care about DB Impl, a Repo Layer should contemplate that droping Account must drop AccountProfile. I'm wrong? Thanks.

Comment: To do this with current implementation, you should use 1:1 mapping and have both `Account` and `AccountProfile` modelled as entities. Changes from the `Account` entity will be then cascaded (so if you remove account, AP will be removed as well). https://mikro-orm.io/docs/cascading/

Comment: You can also set the relation as `eager` so the profile will be always loaded when you load an account.